# Animation inside UICollectionViewCell doesn't run when "awakeFromNib" runs.

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

I am working on a UICollectionViewController with Cell's that contain inner "UIView"s that are animated when shown (just a simple y axis movement).

My problem is, then the cells are first loaded from nib file, the animation doesn't run, but cell are being "reused", animations are being run.

Heres what i do:

```
- (void)loadCellWithAnimation{
    CGRect prevRect = self.viewThatAnimates.frame;
    prevRect.origin.y = prevRect.origin.y+10;
    [UIView animatewithDuration:0.5f animations:^{self.viewThatAnimates.frame = prevRect}];
}
```

and on my collectionViewController:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell loadCellWithAnimation];
    return cell;
}
```

as i told, animation works fine when "reused", but it doesn't run when awake from nib.

I have tested this on several different scenarios and the result is always the same.

Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: Just a little addition, animation can run when i run the animation block with a little delay (dispatch_after with 0.05second delay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because until

```
return cell;
```

has been called from your delegate method, `awakeFromNib` is not called.

You can try animation in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Hope it works.

Cheers.

Comment: When i try to use this section, 2 weird things have happened. First one is this delegate method is called async, and after a long delay (abuot 2-3 secs) when "awakeFromNib" called, Second is i have an array of objects that i use in my collectionviewCells, and this array size is "0" in "didEndDisplayingCell" method, but it looks full on "cellForIndexPath" method. I am guessing the thread for "didDisplayCell" method is called asynchronously before the array generation but it is still weird.

Comment: Separate your animation with you cell initializations and other stuffs. 2-3 secs is a big time, it calls immediately though. If your app uses iOS>=8.0 you can try willDisplayMethod to animate, that might work for you as well.

Comment: You can check this link http://aplus.rs/2014/how-to-animate-in-uicollectionview-items/ if it helps.

Comment: From reference on `collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:`: "Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it disappears" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)